# Multiple groups of columns on excel with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using apache poi version 4.0.0 and I'm trying to make many groups of columns like the image below:
I don't know if it is possible using poi.

[image]

I have tried with `XSSFSHeet.groupColumn()` method inside a loop .

```
            int indexColumnMonth = INDEX_START_RESULTS;
            for(int i =0; i< meses.size(); i++) {
                int columnFim = indexColumnMonth + (turmas.size());
                planilha.groupColumn(indexColumnMonth, columnFim);
                indexColumnMonth = columnFim +1;
            }
```

But the result of that is a sheet with just one group of columns that get all the columns. I've checked if the positions were generated right , but i'ts correct.

Is there a way to do that with POI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[rant start, mode:sarcastic]
As often it lacks the understanding how `Excel` works. Many programmers seems to think they can programming `Excel` functionalities without knowing `Excel`. They might think: "`Excel` why shall I bothering with this? I am a programmer, not a office worker." But for programming `Excel` functionalities one must know `Excel` at first. There is no way around.
[/rant end]

If you are opening the `Excel` file showed in your picture in `Excel`'s GUI and do clicking on the first <kbd>-</kbd> above `J`, then is `J` part of the group? No it is not. And is it part of the second group? No it also is not. That is because there must be at least one column between single groups of columns if they shall appearing as in your picture.

So as shown in your picture you have grouped `E:I`, `K:O` and `Q:U`.

Source:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ExcelGroupColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Test.xlsx");
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(in);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int firstColumn = 4;
        int countGroupedColumns = 5;
        int countGroups = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i < countGroups; i++) {
            sheet.groupColumn(firstColumn, firstColumn + countGroupedColumns - 1);
            firstColumn += countGroupedColumns + 1;
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Test_1.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        workbook.close();

    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you're great